# Test if private method was called in Service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

How should I test if AngularJS private method in the $service was called? I would appreciate any help.

```
angular.module('login')
.service('EventService', [ '$http', '$log', function ($http, $log) {

    function sendEvent(category, action, label, value, customParams) {
        //
    }

    return {
        sendLoginPageEvent: function (action, customParams) {
            if (!customParams) {
                customParams = {};
            }
            customParams.template = 'templateName';

            sendEvent('LoginPage', action, null, null, customParams);
        },

    };

}]);
```

I have some tests like these, but don't seem to work:

```
describe('Test of Cookie Monster service', function() {

    var EventService;
    var sendEventSpy = jasmine.createSpy('eventSpy');


    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
        $provide.value("event", sendEventSpy);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_EventService_) {
        EventService = _EventService_;
    }));


    it('send cookie event', function() {
        EventService.sendLoginPageEvent('action')

        expect(event.sendEvent)
        .toHaveBeenCalledWith('LoginPage', 'action', {template: 'templateName'})
    });
});
```

Is this even a proper approach to test service this way? I'm just starting with testing front-ends so I would be grateful for any kind of advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not private method, this is local function. Variables aren't available outside the scope where they were defined, this may be used to implement Module pattern in JS.

In order to be testable, it should be defined as service method:

```
this.sendEvent = ...
```

Then it could be spied as any other method:

```
spyOn(EventService, 'sendEvent').and.callThrough()
```

Comment: thank you very much, that was exactly the help I was looking for :) all tests pass now!